# Using Nuget to Install into an IIS Applications Root Site

Tags: powershell, iis-7, nuget

I have several ASP.NET application running under a common IIS Site and would like to use a NuGet package to transform their config while copying versioned JavaScript file to the IIS Site's Root application Content folder.

Can NuGet be used like this?  I.e. can it be determine during package installation/updating which IIS Sites root application an ASP.NET project is being run under (using the preinit powershell script for example).

Answer (score 2):

The tool you are looking for is [Octopus Deploy](http://octopusdeploy.com/) It install nuget packages on IIS, as windows service, etc. Moreover it gives raeally nice GUI for management.

Answer (score 0):

NuGet is a dependency manager, and as such is appropriate for use at development/build, not deployment time.

Take a look at Inedo's [BuildMaster](http://inedo.com/buildmaster). It can take care of the process from source control through production deployment. There's also a free version that will most certainly handle your requirements, and it also has a module to manage your configuration files so you don't need to worry about doing transforms.

(disclaimer: I work for Inedo)